How can you determine whether a feature vector extracted from an image is representative for a specific task?
In the task of scoring video frames based on their features for video summarization project,
if the frame features are extracted using pretrained CNNs such as GoogleNet, VGG, and ResNet, how can I determine which network best suits the summarization task?
I know that features alone cant determine the importance of a frame so I'm splitting the video into segments and the segments with higher scores are considered in the summary.
My question is there a method to evaluate the feature representation quality of a frame in relation to its importance score across these models, or should I experiment with each one and choose based on the best performance?

Presumably by assigning some kind of metric to “quality”
